# Are nested templates possible?

Tags: c++

I have two identical functions but with different argument types. Is it possible to combine these into 1 function?

```
template<typename T>
void print_seq(std::vector<T> sequence) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sequence.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << sequence[i] << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void print_seq(std::deque<T> sequence) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sequence.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << sequence[i] << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `template<typename T>
void print_seq(T sequence) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sequence.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << sequence[i] << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}`

Comment: You might want to consider passing iterators instead of the containers themselves. Just like how the STL algorithms do it.

Comment: You may want to consider not calling this function `print_seq` but `operator<<` and passing it a `typename Os`, such that you can do this `cout << object`. Ideally, don't `endl` but have the user end the line: `cout << object << '\n';` ALSO: pass the object as `const&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. As user2717954 commented, you can template the container type itself:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void print_seq(T sequence) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sequence.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << sequence[i] << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

If you only want to allow this function to be called with deques and vectors, you could try using `enable_if`:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t</* expression which is true if T is a deque or vector */, void> print_seq(T sequence) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sequence.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << sequence[i] << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

However, checking if T is a deque or vector is quite more complicated that your current approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually make a stronger and more versetile function by unifying the functions and using a basic template behavior.

Notice at the following code:

```
template <typename Container_t>
void print_seq(Container_t seq)
{
    for (const auto& item: seq)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This function is valid for any type which is:

1. Iterable, meaning that it has both cbegin() and cend() functions (not only vector and deque are suitable for containing sequences!).
2. Its contained type must have operator<< .

This allows you to change the representation of the sequences for "free", without the need to support a new representation specifically (therefore, it is more encapsulated - I don't **need** to know the inner representation of sequence in order to print it!).

P.S Unless you need the index for some computation, whenever possible, you should prefer foreach loop over "regular" for loop - it is easier, and more readable.